# mail() siempre devuelve false

Tags: php

Buenas, estoy intentando enviar desde un formulario los datos que se guarden a un correo gmail, pero la función mail() siempre devuelve false desde mi código PHP, sin embargo desde Mercury sí me lo envía. Estoy usando XAMPP.

El Mercury está configurado siguiendo este [manual](https://wikijc.wordpress.com/2016/04/21/configurar-el-mercury-del-xampp-para-enviar-correos-externos/):

Este es el formulario:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Correo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form action="envio.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" />
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
                <input type="text" name="Teléfono" placeholder="Telefono" />
                <textarea type="text" name="mensaje" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR" id="boton" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

y este el archivo php:

```
<?php
$destino="micuenta@gmail.com";
$nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
$correo=$_POST["correo"];
$telefono=$_POST["telefono"];
$mensaje=$_POST["mensaje"];

$contenido="Nombre: " . $nombre . "\nCorreo: " . $correo . "\nTeléfono: " . $telefono . "\nmensaje" . $mensaje;
$exito=mail($destino, "Contacto", $contenido);

if($exito){
    echo("Bien");
}else{
    echo("Mal");
}
?>
```

Comment: Intentaste configurar el servidor de correo local?

Comment: Si te refieres en Gmail a la configuración de POP3 o IMAP, entonces sí.

Answer (score 0):

Veo que tienes:

```
$correo=$_POST["correo"];
```

y en el input:

```
name="email"
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Por lo que sugiero que pongas:
(a la variable) `$correo=$_POST["email"];`

(al input) `name="email"`

o en su defecto cambiarle:
(a la variable) `$correo=$_POST["correo"];`

(al input) `name="correo"`